# Filter Apollo Client cache results, tried readQuery but returns null

Tags: next.js, apollo-client

I have been trying to work with the Apollo Client cache. So, I don't have to make another call to the server. And to help with paging. The stack I am using is Next.js, Apollo Client on the front-end, Keystone.js on the backend.

I am building an e-commerce site. Right now the user can view products by categories. In each category listing, products can be filtered by different attributes. A simple example would be to filter by color and size. Previously I was storing fetched products in state. And I had filtering working pretty well. The main issue I had was paging. When products are filtered on one page, the other pages are not affected. I read up on [reading/writing to the cache](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction) and thought that would fix the paging issues. But I can't get it to work. Specifically `readQuery`.

So this is what I have tried and honestly I have not found a good example on using `readQuery`. It wasn't until I found this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66696029/apollo-client-client-readquery-returning-null-when-data-is-in-the-cache)  and read the first answer that I realized you have to use the exact same query that first fetched the results. Or do I?

Here is the parent component and it's first query to fetch products.

```js
\\ Products.jsx

function ProductCategory({ page, category, productType }) {
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState();

  const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(ALL_PRODUCTS_FILTERED_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      skipPage: page * perPage - perPage,
      first: perPage,
      category,
      productType: capitalize(productType),
      potency: '0',
    },
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading) {
      setFilteredData(data?.products);
    }
  }, [loading]);

  if (loading)
    return (
      <Processing loading={loading.toString()}>
        <LoadingIcon tw="animate-spin" />
        Loading
      </Processing>
    );

  if (error) return <DisplayError error={error} />;

  return (
    <>
      <Filters
        loading={loading}
        products={data.products}
        setFilteredData={setFilteredData}
        productType={productType}
        category={category}
        page={page}
      />

      <ContainerStyles hasBgPrimaryLight20>
        <ProductGridStyles>
          {filteredData &&
            filteredData?.map((product) => (
              <Product key={product.id} product={product} />
            ))}
        </ProductGridStyles>
      </ContainerStyles>
    </>
  );
}

ProductCategory.propTypes = {
  page: PropTypes.number,
  category: PropTypes.string,
  productType: PropTypes.string,
};

export default ProductCategory;
```

My ALL_PRODUCTS_FILTERED_QUERY query:

```js
export const ALL_PRODUCTS_FILTERED_QUERY = gql`
  query ALL_PRODUCTS_FILTERED_QUERY(
    $skipPage: Int = 0
    $first: Int
    $category: String
    $productType: String
    $potency: String
  ) {
    products(
      take: $first
      skip: $skipPage
      orderBy: [{ name: asc }]
      where: {
        productType: { every: { name: { equals: $productType } } }
        category: { slug: { equals: $category } }
        flower: { potency: { gte: $potency } }
      }
    ) {
      id
      name
      slug
      inventory
      price
      priceThreshold {
        name
        price
        amount
      }
      hotDeal
      topPick
      category {
        slug
        name
      }
      photos {
        id
        image {
          publicUrl
        }
        altText
      }
      description
      status
      vendor {
        id
        name
        vendor_ID
      }
      flower {
        label
        weight
        potency
        strain
        trimMethod
        environment
      }
      oil {
        label
        weight
        potency
        cbd
        oilType
        solventUsed
      }
      concentrate {
        label
        weight
        potency
        strain
        type
      }
      preRoll {
        label
        size
        potency
        strain
        type
        tube
      }
      machine {
        label
        model
        modelYear
        condition
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

My `Filters.jsx` component is what's using the `readQuery` method to read from the cache and filter results. Or so I hoped. You'll see I am passing the setFilteredData hook from `Products.jsx` so once products are returned from the cache I am updating the state. Right now I am getting `null`.

For simplicity I have removed all filters except potency and imports.

```js
\\ Filters.jsx

function Filters({ category, setFilteredData, page, productType }) {
  const [potencies, setPotencies] = useState([]);
  const [potency, setPotency] = useState();
  const { checkboxfilters, setCheckboxFilters } = useFilters([
    ...strainList,
    ...environmentList,
    ...potencyList,
    ...oilTypeList,
    ...solventList,
    ...trimList,
    ...concentrateTypeList,
    ...prerollTypeList,
    ...tubeList,
    ...priceList,
  ]);

  const client = useApolloClient();

  async function fetchProducts(flowerPotency) {
    console.log(
      page * perPage - perPage,
      category,
      flowerPotency,
      capitalize(productType)
    );
    try {
      const data = await client.readQuery({
        query: ALL_PRODUCTS_FILTERED_QUERY,
        variables: {
          skipPage: page * perPage - perPage,
          first: perPage,
          category,
          productType: capitalize(productType),
          potency: flowerPotency,
        },
      });
      setFilteredData(data.products);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error: ', error);
    }
  }

  const updateCheckboxFilters = (index) => {
    setCheckboxFilters(
      checkboxfilters.map((filter, currentIndex) =>
        currentIndex === index
          ? {
              ...filter,
              checked: !filter.checked,
            }
          : filter
      )
    );
  };

  const handlePotencyCheck = (e, index) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setPotency(e.target.value);
      fetchProducts(e.target.value);
    } else {
      setPotency();
    }
    updateCheckboxFilters(index);
  };

  return (
    <FilterStyles>
      <FiltersContainer>
        <Popover tw="relative">
          <Popover.Button tw="text-sm flex">
            Sort{' '}
            <ChevronDownIcon
              tw="ml-2 h-4 w-4  text-accent"
              aria-hidden="true"
            />
          </Popover.Button>
          <Popover.Panel/>
        </Popover>
        <div tw="flex space-x-4">
          {category === 'flower' ||
          category === 'oil' ||
          category === 'concentrate' ? (
            <Popover tw="relative">
              <Popover.Button tw="text-sm flex">
                Potency{' '}
                <ChevronDownIcon
                  tw="ml-2 h-4 w-4  text-accent"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                />
              </Popover.Button>
              <FilterPopOverPanelStyles>
                {potencyList.map((filter) => {
                  const checkedIndex = checkboxfilters.findIndex(
                    (check) => check.name === filter.name
                  );
                  return (
                    <Checkbox
                      key={`potency-${checkedIndex}`}
                      isChecked={checkboxfilters[checkedIndex].checked}
                      checkHandler={(e) => handlePotencyCheck(e, checkedIndex)}
                      label={filter.name.slice(2)}
                      value={filter.value.slice(2)}
                      index={checkedIndex}
                    />
                  );
                })}
              </FilterPopOverPanelStyles>
            </Popover>
          ) : null}
        </div>
      </FiltersContainer>
      <ActiveFilters>
        <ActiveFiltersContainer>
          <ActiveFiltersHeader>Applied Filters:</ActiveFiltersHeader>
          <div tw="flex">
            {potencies.map((potency, index) => (
              <button
                key={index}
                type="button"
                onClick={() => handleRemoveFilter(potency)}
              >
                {potency}% <XIcon tw="w-4 h-4 ml-2 text-accent" />
                <span tw="sr-only">Click to remove</span>
              </button>
            ))}
          </div>
        </ActiveFiltersContainer>
      </ActiveFilters>
    </FilterStyles>
  );
}

Filters.propTypes = {
  loading: PropTypes.any,
  products: PropTypes.any,
  setFilteredData: PropTypes.func,
};

export default Filters;
```

I expected it to return products from the cache based on the potency passed to the query. Instead, I get null. I thought using the exact same query and variables would do the trick. What am I doing wrong? Am I using `readQuery` correctly? I did try `readFragment` and got that to successfully work, but it only returns one product. So I know reading from the cache is working.

Answer (score 0):

You're making your life unnecessarily complicated. If you're looking for data that's been previously returned by `useQuery` or `client.readQuery` you can query it again with `{fetchPolicy: "cache-only"}`

Initial query:

```
const data = await client.readQuery({
  query: ALL_PRODUCTS_FILTERED_QUERY,
  variables: {
    skipPage: page * perPage - perPage,
    first: perPage,
    category,
    productType: capitalize(productType),
    potency: flowerPotency,
  },
});
```

Query from cache:

```
const data = await client.readQuery({
  query: ALL_PRODUCTS_FILTERED_QUERY,
  variables: {
    skipPage: page * perPage - perPage,
    first: perPage,
    category,
    productType: capitalize(productType),
    potency: flowerPotency,
  },
  fetchPolicy: "cache-only",  // <-- fetchPolicy!
});
```

Also you don't need either `useState` or `useEffect` to copy the data coming back from your query - it's not adding any value.

Comment: I definitely knew adding to state was overkill. Hence why I was trying to work with the cache. But many thanks! I will give this a try tonight.

Comment: That wasn't the magic sauce unfortunately. Still returning null. I'm digging into the Apollo Cache and finding some things that make me wonder if the cache is setup correctly. I'll add to my question.

Answer (score 0):

After digging back through my code, I realized I had pagination setup incorrectly as it was initially setup for a single product category. Now that I have multiple categories my code needs refactored to take this into account. So conditions were never being met and always fetching from the network. Plus I need to really sit down and truly understand how Apollo client works.

The first issue was as simple as arguments named incorrectly. Initially I had `args` being passed into my `read()` function named `skip,first`. Doing an update last year for Keystone those got renamed to `skip,take`.

Second issue was my `PAGINATION_QUERY` was getting the count for all `products`. But now since they are split into categories, I just need the product count for the current category.

After these two tweaks I can now use `readQuery` to query the cache.

Comment: Things are still off with the cache, pagination and filtering results. If anyone has an example of running a query, filtering the cache based on user interactions (filter by size, color) I'd greatly appreciate it. Does filtering the cache constitute a mutation? If that's the case what happens when someone removes a filter? Is a new query ran because we ran a mutation and those results were removed from the cache?